# How to change tag name with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am using python + BeautifulSoup to parse an HTML document.

Now I need to replace all `<h2 class="someclass">` elements in an HTML document, with `<h1 class="someclass">`.

How can I change the tag name, without changing anything else in the document?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I don't know how you're accessing `tag` but the following works for me:

```
import BeautifulSoup

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = """
<html>
<h2 class='someclass'>some title</h2>
<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
   <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
</ul>
</html>

    """
    soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(data)
    h2 = soup.find('h2')
    h2.name = 'h1'
    print soup
```

Output of `print soup` command is:

```
<html>
<h1 class='someclass'>some title</h1>
<ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
<li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
<li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
</ul>
</html>
```

As you can see, `h2` became `h1`. And nothing else in the document changed. I am using Python 2.6 and BeautifulSoup 3.2.0.

If you have more than one `h2` and you want to change them all, you could simple do:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(your_data)
while True: 
    h2 = soup.find('h2')
    if not h2:
        break
    h2.name = 'h1'
```

Comment: don't know why it hasn't worked for me before. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's just:

```
tag.name = 'new_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

From [BeautifulSoup docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html)

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, Tag
soup = BeautifulSoup("<h2 class="someclass">TEXTHERE</h2>")
tag = Tag(soup, "h1", [("class", "someclass")])
tag.insert(0, "TEXTHERE")
soup.h2.replaceWith(tag)
print soup
# <h1 class="someclass">TEXTHERE</h1>
```

Comment: I think this will remove all the content of the h2 tag. I just want to replace the tag name and leave everything else intact.