# Retain the children elements in beautifulSoup python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have markup as:

```
<p>Sample text. Click <a href="google.com">Here</a></p>
```

I want to replace the `<p>` tag with `<span>` without changing the children or text of the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task can be done using `replaceWith`. You have to duplicate the element you want to use as the replacement, and then feed that as the argument to `replaceWith`. The [documentation for `replaceWith`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Replacing%20one%20Element%20with%20Another) is pretty clear on how to do this.

In any case you could read this question [How to change tag name with BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289189/how-to-change-tag-name-with-beautifulsoup)